# clang++ crash with template wrapping aligned class

Tags: c++, clang++

I am seeing a weird crash trying to use a wrapper template class around aligned struct/class. The following program is crashing when compiled with clang, while working properly with both gcc and visual studio.

```
struct __attribute__( ( aligned( 16 ) ) ) AlignedStruct
{ 
    AlignedStruct( ) { } 
    float x,y,z,w;
};

template <typename P1> class Wrapper
{
public:
    P1 Inner;
};

int main( )
{
    Wrapper<AlignedStruct> * t1 = new Wrapper<AlignedStruct>( );
    return 1;
}
```

The crash seems to be while calling AlignedStruct constructor (if I remove it, clang compiled code runs as well).

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Thanks!

Edit:

The crash occurs with clang 3.4.2 under cygwin32 and cygwin64
and clang 3.4.1 under Ubuntu 14.04 (x32) and Ubuntu 14.10 (x32)

It does not, however, occur when testing with clang 3.4.1 under FreeBSD 10.1 (x32) and OS X Yosemite.

I've tried playing around with compilation flags but I can't seem to be able to make any difference with those, so I am just running `clang++ file.cpp`

Comment: What version of clang, what platform, what flags ... ?

Comment: Why on earth are you returning 1?

Comment: It compiles and runs fine without any crash in my clang3.4.1, Ubuntu 12.04 (**x64**).

Comment: I wouldn't expect a problem in 64 bits. In 32 bits, my guess is that you tell the compiler that the type is aligned, so it uses an aligned SIMD instruction in the constructor, but operator new only returns memory with an alignment of 8, so it crashes.